# Unity + Ready Player Me Avatar with C# script. Voicehandler/lipsync working in Unity Hub but not in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, trying to create a very basic proof of concept where a button click will trigger an audio file to be played from an https url and a Ready Player Me avatar will lip sync with the audio file using the 'Voice Handler' component which comes with the Ready Player Me avatar. I am trying to build and deploy this for WebGL.

This concept works fine when I run the 'game' in Unity Hub but the lip sync animation doesn't work when I build and run, even locally. I receive the following error which repeats in the browser console whilst the audio file plays:
`AudioClip.GetData failed; AudioClip  contains no data` I tried Googling this error but didn't find anything useful.

Note, when I run this script in Unity, my debug line shows the audioclip's load state as 'Loaded', but on the built version it logs as 'Unloaded', despite the audio still playing.

I have deployed a version publicly here where this can be observed: https://avatar-jovo-test.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

This is the script I am running on the button click:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class BotAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource botAudioSource;

    public void GetResponse()
    {
          
    StartCoroutine(GetBotAudio());
    }
    private IEnumerator GetBotAudio()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip("https://avatar-jovo-test.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-speech-polly.mp3", AudioType.MPEG))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                AudioClip clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
                botAudioSource.Stop();
                botAudioSource.clip = clip;
                botAudioSource.clip.LoadAudioData();
                Debug.Log("Load State: " + botAudioSource.clip.loadState);
                botAudioSource.Play();
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the following approach:
make a link in your script onto voiceHandler

```
public VoiceHandler voiceHandler;
....
AudioClip clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
// To play clip use function PlayAudioClip
voiceHandler.PlayAudioClip(clip);
....
// To stop audio playback do it like this
voiceHandler.AudioSource.Stop();
```